# Returning data from multiple sql tables entity framework web api

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, api

I have a DB stored locally with a number of different tables, all connected together like this:

[image]

I am trying to create a web API for these with entity framework on vs. My controller looks like this:

```
public class CourseController : ApiController
{
    QubDBEntities entities = new QubDBEntities();

    public IEnumerable<Course> Get()
    {
        using (QubDBEntities entities = new QubDBEntities())
        {
            return entities.Courses.ToList();
        }
    }

    public Course Get(Guid id)
    {
        using (QubDBEntities entities = new QubDBEntities())
        {
            return entities.Courses.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }

    public Course Get(string day, DateTime time, int duration,string moduleRef, string moduleName, string courseRef,
        string roomRef,string roomName, string roomFloor, int roomNumber, string buildingRef, string buildingName)
    {
        //how do I join tables inside here so that I can 
        //return the courses with this view?^
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to join these tables using entity framework? My SQL select statement here:

```
SELECT
    dbo.TimeTable.Day, dbo.TimeTable.StartTime, dbo.TimeTable.Duration, dbo.Module.ModuleRef
    , dbo.Module.ModuleName, dbo.Course.CourseRef, dbo.Room.RoomRef, dbo.Room.RoomName
    , dbo.Room.RoomFloor, dbo.Room.RoomNumber, dbo.Building.BuildingRef, dbo.Building.BuildingName

FROM dbo.Room INNER JOIN
         dbo.TimeTable INNER JOIN
         dbo.Module ON dbo.TimeTable.ModuleId = dbo.Module.Id ON dbo.Room.Id = dbo.TimeTable.RoomId INNER JOIN
         dbo.Building ON dbo.Room.BuildingId = dbo.Building.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.Course INNER JOIN
         dbo.CourseModule ON dbo.Course.Id = dbo.CourseModule.CourseId ON dbo.Module.Id = dbo.CourseModule.ModuleId
```

Any help / pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is three ways you can return results from joining tables in Entity Framework :
1- using `Linq` , please refer to [link here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/03/25/inner-outer-lets-all-join-together-with-linq.aspx)
2- using `include` , please refer to [link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
3- using raw sql like using generic function `_context.Database.SqlQuery<type>(sqlString)`